# Program connects via USB only if called with sudo

Tags: usb, sudo

I have downloaded JLink package and unpacked it to `/home/mkru/ARM/JLink_Linux_V498a_x86_64`. Then I have added this path to my PATH variable. When I try to execute JLinkExe I get the following error:

```
Can not connect to J-Link via USB.
```

When I try to execute it with sudo I get:

```
sudo: JLinkExe: command not found
```

The only way to execute it with success is:

1. to change directory with `cd /home/mkru/ARM/JLink_Linux_V498a_x86_64`
2. then run `sudo ./JLinkExe`

Why does it work like that and how can I change this behaviour ? I would like to use `JLinkExe` without `sudo` and without the need to be in this specific directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain features require root elevations. Low-level USB interaction is one of them, I experienced the same when I wanted to use my LEGO NXT robot.

First of all, if the program only works with sudo, move it away from your home. I suggest moving it to `/opt/jlink/` or something like that

To keep having to `cd` to the executable directory, add it to the global bath in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, instead of your home bashrc. Also, define an alias which automatically executes the program with root elevations. The additions to the file may look like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jlink    #or wherever you moved it
alias JLinkExe='sudo /opt/jlink/JLinkExe'
```

Now you can execute the program just by entering `JLinkExe` (you could even assign a easier-to-enter name in the alias, e.g. simply `alias jlink='sudo /opt/jlink/JLinkExe'`).

However, you'll still be asked for your password, as the program still requires root elevation. To circumvent that, you can create an entry in your sudo setup. For this, execute `sudo visudo` and add this line to the end of the file

```
mkru ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/jlink/JLinkExe
```

After saving this, you (and only you, i.e. user `mkru`) shouldn't be asked for giving the program root elevations any more. Keep in mind that it will still be running with elevated privileges.

---

**NOTE:** If the program has a GUI, create the alias as `alias jlink='sudo gksudo /opt/jlink/JLinkExe'` to prevent it from messing up ownerships in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly better solution. Just copy the `99-jlink.rules` file (part of the downloaded package) into `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and it should work like a charm.